# Why do we need Context parameter in ArrayAdapter<T>(context,resId,T[] objects)?

Tags: android

I've searched on stack overflow and google too. But can't figure out why do we need to pass the Context parameter?
   All ArrayAdapter  have to do is, take a layout resId to return us desired view from data set here "objects" parameter.

Comment: Inflating a view requires a `context`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Context is used for creating mInflater in ArrayAdapter. 
You can see source code here.
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.0_r1/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java#ArrayAdapter.0mInflater

```
    private void More ...init(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<T> objects) {
270        mContext = context;
271        mInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
272        mResource = mDropDownResource = resource;
273        mObjects = objects;
274        mFieldId = textViewResourceId;
275    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Context` is used to [get a reference to the `LayoutInflater` (retrieved through `getSystemService`)](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java#L310), which the `ArrayAdapter` will need to use for inflating the provided layout resource into a view which can be populated with the items that get passed in.